# When to use "extend" and when to use "extent"?

Tags: word-difference, spelling

What is the difference between extend and extent, when to use which one?

I am wondering, is there a quick rule to know whether one should use extend or extent? I know that it is "to what extend" (as in to what degree), "extent" (as in degree), "extend" (as in expand), but there are more forms and I am getting always getting confused between them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Extend" is strictly a verb.

> She ***extends*** her hand in friendship.
>   He ***extended*** the antenna, hoping to get better reception.

"Extent" is strictly a noun.

> To what ***extent*** does physical exercise relieve moodiness?
>   She walked the ***extent*** of the plank, then descended into the sea below.

Comment: I expected this, but apparently my book is wrong that it is "to what extend" (it should be "to what extent", as in your answer, I checked in a dictionary). I will accept your answer in 6 minutes.